# Transpile ES6 import/export with babel 6 and gulp

Tags: gulp, babeljs, es6-modules

I would like to use ES6 import / export. I use Gulp 3.9 with babel.js 6.
I want to import functions.js into form.js.
I get the following error:

```
ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

**== MY SETUP ==**

**functions.js**

```
var helper = {
  insertAfter: function(el, elParent) {
    elParent.parentNode.insertBefore(el, elParent.nextSibling);
  },
  resetTextfield: function(el) {
    let reinitTextfield = new mdc.textField.MDCTextField(el);
    let label = el.firstElementChild.nextElementSibling;

    label.classList.remove('mdc-text-field__label--float-above');
    reinitTextfield.value = '';
  }
}

// Export
export default helper;
```

**form.js**

```
// Import functions.js
import helper from './functions.js';
```

**My Gulp task:**

```
// babel js task - transpile our Javascript into the build directory
gulp.task("js-babel", () => {
    $.fancyLog("-> Transpiling Javascript via Babel...");
    return gulp.src(pkg.globs.babelJs)
        .pipe($.plumber({errorHandler: onError}))
        .pipe($.newer({dest: pkg.paths.build.js}))
        .pipe($.babel())
        .pipe($.size({gzip: true, showFiles: true}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(pkg.paths.build.js));
});
```

**.babelrc:**

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015"],
  "compact": true
}
```

I thought babel.js transpiles the JS and I can use import / export.
Now, am I reading that I need Browserify with Babelify ?!
Will that replace my "js-babel" task?

How should I rebuild my task?